# Are sections inside Sitecore Webforms for Marketers restricted to 10?

Tags: wffm

I am using Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 160519) + Web Forms for Marketers 8.1.rev. 160523. I created a sample form with 12 sections and 1 single-line text field in each section (total: 12 text-box fields).

When I am debugging the list of field/value in a custom Save Action in "AdaptedResultList", the field value of second Section's field + field value of eleventh section's field is getting replaced with value of 12th section's field.

If I keep sections upto only 10 then I am perfectly getting the value .

Is Sitecore WFFM restricted up to 10 sections?

```
Not Working If :-   Working If :- 
Sec 1 :- Field 1    Sec 1 :- Field 1
Sec 2 :- Field 2    Sec 2 :- Field 2
Sec 3 :- Field 3    Sec 3 :- Field 3
Sec 4 :- Field 4    Sec 4 :- Field 4
Sec 5 :- Field 5    Sec 5 :- Field 5
Sec 6 :- Field 6    Sec 6 :- Field 6
Sec 7 :- Field 7    Sec 7 :- Field 7
Sec 8 :- Field 8    Sec 8 :- Field 8
Sec 9 :- Field 9    Sec 9 :- Field 9
Sec 10:- Field 10   Sec 10:- Field 10,Field 11,Field 12
Sec 11 :- Field 11  
Sec 12 :- Field 12
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a known defect. You should request hotfix **434449** from Sitecore Support.

Or just follow these steps:

1. Download the hotfix DLL:
   a) For Sitecore 8.0: [**Sitecore.Support.434449.dll**](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ajr_7Ne_eB0ula4h5lUvo8Cuemmeog)
   b) For Sitecore 8.1 Update 2 or later: [**Sitecore.Support.434449.81.dll**](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ajr_7Ne_eB0ul6Fo7DW2D83ESQiVrQ)
2. Put the DLL to your website's `bin` folder.
3. Create a `.config` patch under `App_Config/Include/zzz`.
   a) If you have Sitecore 8.0, put the following content in the patch file:

   ```
   <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:x="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
     <sitecore>
       <pipelines>
         <initialize>
           <processor
             type="Sitecore.Support.Forms.Mvc.Pipelines.AddCustomMetadataProvider, Sitecore.Support.434449"
             patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Pipelines.AddCustomMetadataProvider, Sitecore.Forms.Mvc']" />
         </initialize>
     </sitecore>
   </configuration>
   ```

   b) For Sitecore 8.1 Update 2 or later:

   ```
   <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:x="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
     <sitecore>
       <pipelines>
         <initialize>
           <processor
             type="Sitecore.Support.Forms.Mvc.Pipelines.Initialize.AddCustomMetadataProvider, Sitecore.Support.434449.81"
             patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Pipelines.Initialize.AddCustomMetadataProvider, Sitecore.Forms.Mvc']">
             <param name="perRequestStorage" ref="/sitecore/wffm/data/perRequestStorage" />
             <param name="corePipeline" ref="/sitecore/wffm/corePipelineWrapper" />
           </processor>
         </initialize>
     </sitecore>
   </configuration>
   ```

Source: https://sitecorelogy.com/2016/07/19/fixed-sitecore-wffm-creates-a-duplicate-field-section-upon-submission-when-exceeded-to-10-sections/

Comment: As an aside, Sitecore has setup an account on GitHub for support patches like these at https://github.com/SitecoreSupport. If you submit a ticket and request it, they'll likely put this patch up there for long-term access.

Comment: I am getting this error  :-  Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.Support.Forms.Mvc.Pipelines.AddCustomMetadataProvider, Sitecore.Support.434449.81 (method: Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateType(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).

Comment: @Shailesh I have fixed the config patch in my answer. Please try again.

Comment: Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.Support.Forms.Mvc.Pipelines.Initialize.AddCustomMetadataProvider. No matching constructor was found.

Comment: @Shailesh I have updated my answer once again. Please try it. The linked blog article is not completely correct, unfortunately.